# Left side bar gets overlapped with fixed top menu when i scroll my site?

Tags: html, css, web-services, web-applications, dhtml

When i scroll my site all content goes well below under top fixed menu, but only left side bar gets overlapped with it.Can anyone tell where i am doing wrong????? This is my site . http://www.techonicals.com

Answer (score -1, accepted):

in css file set `.menu {z-index:1}` or more than 1 :о)

Answer (score 2):

Add a z-index to your menu and this will fix your problem:

```
.menu {z-index:10000;}
```

Comment: works fine in firefox and chrome experiencing problems in IE 9

Answer (score -1):

you must use `z-index` whit a hight value
checkout this site
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

you can check the max value and what happen when is exceeded here

http://www.puidokas.com/max-z-index/

Comment: works fine in firefox and chrome experiencing problems in IE 9